# Wpf - Using Shapes as a Resource

Tags: wpf, resources, shapes

Iv'e got a Rectangle in my resource dictionary which i would like to place inside numerous Grid objects

```
<Rectangle  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="10" x:Key="ShadowRect">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1.7,0.603" StartPoint="0.3,0.603">
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.009"/>                    
         </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>                               
 </Rectangle>
```

Now of course i could place it directly like so :

```
 <Grid>
     <Rectangle  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="10" >
        <Rectangle.Fill>
          <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1.7,0.603" StartPoint="0.3,0.603">
              <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
          <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.009"/>                  
           </LinearGradientBrush>
         </Rectangle.Fill>                              
     </Rectangle>
 </Grid>
```

but i would like to use it as a Resource so i do not have to write this XAML for every Grid ,

how can i place the rectangle using it's resource key ?

Comment: How about defining it as control template and then use that control template as resource?

Comment: like maybe defining it as a style for a ContentControl, good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a Rectangle Style instead of a Rectangle in your ResourceDictionary:

```
<Style x:Key="ShadowRectStyle" TargetType="Rectangle">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="10"/>
    <Setter Property="Fill">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1.7,0.603" StartPoint="0.3,0.603">
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.009"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then use it like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource ShadowRectStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```